# Using forward reference

Tags: c++, header-files

I have a circular header problem that is different from most of the ones already asked on here.  I have two classes that depend on each other but *not as members* so don't run into the problem of the compiler not being able to calculate the class's sizes.  So I'm able to use a forward-declaration to break the cycle.

However, I don't want the client to have to include both these headers to use my classes.  The headers should be self-contained so the user doesn't need to be aware of this dependency.  Is there some way to do this?

Edit: the tricky part is that A and B must be defined header-only.

In header A.hpp

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP

#include "B.hpp"

struct A
{
    B foo() { ... }
};

#endif
```

In header B.hpp

```
#ifndef B_HPP
#define B_HPP

struct A;

struct B
{
    void bar()
    {
        A a = A();
        ...
    }
};

#endif
```

In main.cpp

```
#include "B.hpp"
B().bar(); // error: 'a' uses undefined class 'A'
```

Comment: If `A.hpp` includes `B.hpp`, why not include `A.hpp` instead of `B.hpp` in `main.cpp`?

Comment: `A` is actually an internal implementation detail of `B`.  I don't really want the clients to know anything about it

Comment: Is `B` supposed to be a header-only implementation? Otherwise, why is the code for `bar` in the header file?

Comment: I'd say actually move the class over to `B.hpp` then if belongs to `B`.

Answer (score 3):

Header B.hpp

```
#ifndef B_HPP
#define B_HPP

struct A;

struct B
{
   void bar();
};

#endif
```

Source B.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"

void B::bar()
{
   A a;
}
```

**EDIT.** So, if you want header-only implementation, then use AndreyT solution.

Comment: Inline property is lost in this approach.

Comment: @AndreyT Premature optimization is evil, not so?

Comment: I should have said I wanted A and B to be header-only. This is for a library.

Comment: @ForEveR: `inline` ceased to be an optimization long time ago. Optimizations should be left to the compiler. Your responsibility is to make sure your are not taking away the optimization opportunities from the compiler. Doing so would be even greater evil than premature optimization.

Comment: @AndreyT But inline may not be lost if realisation is in .cpp file. It depends on linker.

Comment: @ForEveR: Maybe. But that's still a rather exotic capability.

Answer (score 2):

If both headers contain code that requires the other type to be complete, then in general case it cannot possibly be implemented by self-contained headers.

In your specific example (which is too simple to be representative), you can simply move the definition if `B::bar` to `A.hpp`:

```
inline void B::bar()
{
    A a = A();
    ...
}
```

But, of course, having methods of `B` defined in `A.hpp` doesn't look very elegant.

If the "inlinedness" of `B::bar` is important to you, the "industrial" solution would involve placing the definition of `B::bar` into an additional header file `B_aux.hpp`. When you include the headers, you should include the "aux" ones after all "normal" ones are included, i.e. in `main.cpp` you'd have

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
#include "C.hpp"
...
#include "B_aux.hpp"
...
```

But this is, obviously, not a "self-contained" approach.

Comment: If I move the code to A.hpp and include A.hpp in several different .cpp files, will that not lead to a multiple-definition link error?

Comment: I couldn't care less about the (imaginary) performance 'advantages' of inline so that's not a problem

Comment: @thehouse: If you put `B::bar` into `A.hpp` it will not produce multiple definition errors as long as it is declared `inline`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `#include "A.hpp"` to the *bottom* of B.hpp. You'll still have a circular include, but now it won't hurt anything.

Comment: I guess that's kind of like moving the class over without actually moving it :p

Comment: @MarkRansom  I've tried this both inside and outside the include guards but it doesn't help.  Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Usually circular includes are a sign that the two types are closely related, and that could mean that they are a single component. If that is the case, then just merge the two headers into a single header for the component, with the type declarations first and the member function definitions at the end, when both types have been fully defined.